# How does the area under a $F$-$v$ graph relate to power?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, power

The Force-velocity graph for linear motion with constant acceleration from 0 to 15 m/s, followed by linear motion with constant power from 15 to 60 m/s is shown below

[image: Force/velocity]

I can then draw the Power-velocity graph:

[image: Power/velocity]

The average power is: $P_{avg} = \cfrac{A_p}{\Delta v}$

Now, I thought that the area $A_f$ (that has the same dimensions as power) will be the average power as calculated before, but it isn't.
So, what does the area $A_f$ represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially wanting to compare the following two expressions that have units of power during the process with constant power $P$.

$$A_f=\int_{v_1}^{v_2}F\,\text dv=P\int_{v_1}^{v_2}\frac{\text dv}{v}=P\ln\left(\frac{v_2}{v_1}\right)$$
$$P_\text{avg}=\frac{A_p}{\Delta v}=\frac{1}{v_2-v_1}\int_{v_1}^{v_2}P\,\text dv=P$$

Obviously, these are not the same thing. Which is a good lesson to show that same units $\neq$ same value.

Instantaneous power is given by $P=\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf v$, so any $(v,F)$ point on the first graph is related to the corresponding $(v,P)$ graph through this equation. i.e. $(v,F)\to(v,Fv)=(v,P)$, and this is how the graphs are related.

However, for your proposed area $A_f$, you are adding up (integrating) a bunch of $F\text d v$ terms. While these have units of power, it is not related to the instantaneous power $P$. I am not sure if it has any useful physical significance.

Comment: How did you go from

$$\int F* dv$$  to $$ \int \frac{Pdv}{dv}$$

Comment: @DDD4C4U For constant power $P$, $F=P/v$, so $$\int F\,\text dv=\int\frac Pv\,\text dv$$